# Custom CSS style for specific in-page block

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The *(relatively)* new attribute **scoped**, allows to set specific CSS styling rules for a subset of an HTML page, which is what I am trying to do.

## So, why a question?

### Let's start by saying what I am in to:

I am getting contents from external sites, which I want to publish inside a Wordpress blog. Which works great. But, let's say I want to show those contents with their original style (id est. the css style they have assigned in the original source).

### This is how I approached the issue:

When getting the content (via php scrap), I prepend a `<style>CSS</style>` string to it, with the right properties.

### Why not "scoped"?

Because when publishing, wordpress wraps the `<style>CSS</style>` snippet into a `<p>...</p>`, and it stops being effective.

### Does it work?

Yes, since let's-say-all browsers will apply the CSS rules wherever they are.

### So, what's wrong?

Because

- It generates an extra `<p></p>` without semantic information.
- Wordpress will print `<style>whatever...` as an excerpt.

I tried to play around with the wordpress integrated KSES library, to stop it from removing the `<style>` snippet when publishing, and it worked... but I cannot find out how to make it not print CSS properties as part of post excerpts. So, instead of going that hacky way, I am asking your clever minds, if you can think about a more clever alternative to achieve the same thing.

### A few considerations

- Every post might have a different CSS, so it must somehow go together.
- I thought about postpending the `<style>` snippet at the end of the post, so wordpress won't show it as part of excerpts. But, how good is that idea at all?

Thanks for taking your time to read me.

Comment: Does it have to go through Wordpress' _"magic"_ HTML processor? That seems like asking for trouble.

Comment: @Halcyon I do not know what you are referencing to (the kses library?). I do not need any HTML processor since I take care of cleaning the HTML before publishing it. Can I disable that thing? I suppose it will print the post as it is... but what about excerpts? (If the wordpress fucntion crops just the first few words, ignoring tags, it will keep doing the same). Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm referencing your problem statement: _Because when publishing, wordpress wraps the `<style>CSS</style>` snippet into a `<p>...</p>`, and it stops being effective._

Comment: You should look into the [browser support for `scoped`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) before going any further.